# Adjust content compression and hugging properties for more than 2 elements

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, interface-builder

I want to place 2 labels and 1 image in such way that,

- FirstLabel is aligned on left and its content can compress
- Icon stays to the right of First Label
- SecondLabel is aligned on the right and its contents will not compress

[image]

I tried to increase compression property of SecondLabel to 751, but it forces me to also increase SecondLabel's hugging property to 252. This leads to Icon being pulled near SecondLabel (that i do not want)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do that.

1. This is the easiest and you're actually almost done. In your second label, just set its `textAlignment` to `right`. That's it.
2. The other way is use `UIStackView`. Set the leading stackView (of First Label and `UIImageView`)'s distribution to `Fill Proportionally`, and play with other properties of your two stackViews.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Glenn. Yes, i ended up with reducing contentHugging of SecondLabel to 250 and Setting text-alignment to Right.

Comment: Cool. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, you may mark it as accepted/answer.